# return JSON jquery - Unexpected token w

Tags: jquery

I have this in jquery to show data when I click in a link.

first I take the link and use ajax to call a function

```
    var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' ),
        eldata = {
            link: $itemEl.data('link')
        };

    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: eldata.link,
        success: function(data){
            self.updateData(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
        }
    });
```

I return a  JSON data and now create a object to take the data an show its
I return this data

```
<?php
echo  json_encode($this->items);
?>
```

But I obtain this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.parseJSON jquery.min.js:2
$.ajax.success grid.js:471
k jquery.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
y jquery.min.js:2
send.d
```

and I have no idea! any suggestion?

Comment: validate your JSON here: http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$.ajax` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) automatically parses JSON for you, so `data` will be a JS object already. Trying to parse that will lead to its stringification and invalid JSON. Instead just pass the `data` to your `updateData` method directly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.$item.children('a').data('link'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: $.proxy(this, 'updateData')
});
```